# PassBook + ios 6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, passbook

In Pass.Json file, how to write a code for adding button and how to add hyperlink text, which dynamically update the link, after user click the hyperlink text?
Please let me know if someone come across with same requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a button or hyperlink to a pass.

There is a fairly clumsy workaround to update a pass based off a user action that takes advantage of the fact the URLs, phone numbers, dates and addresses that appear on the *back* of the pass are automatically made clickable.

So while you cannot add a button or hyperlink text per-se, you could add a link to a script that when clicked on, triggers a push update that updates the pass with your new content.  [This pass](http://mystic8ball.com) contains a good example, and the source code is available [here](http://code.google.com/p/passkit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/PHP/examples/Mystic%208%20Ball).

Comment: Thanks for answer. As if you don't want to disclose the entire link, once user click the pass, it should updated with the required link from the background, just like address functionality in pass.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible. The naked link is the best that you can do within the current framework.

Comment: if they support html, then it should possible.. do you know any tutorial, about updating the pass, and how to use push notification to update the pass..

Comment: That's the whole point `pass.json` does NOT support HTML.  The simplest way to get started is to use the [Ruby sample code](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=passbook) that Apple provide.  There are a number of fragmented tutorials, but nothing that goes from start to finish.

Comment: if i want to add some url, with out exposing the full url text, is there any way to do that?